# HTML Canvas frames to mp4

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mp4

Saving the content of an html canvas can be done by calling the element's `toDataURL()` method, this will save it as an png file encoded in base64. Would it be possible to somehow merge multiple of these base64 png images into a base64 mp4 video? It dosn't really have to be mp4, as long as it's a video.

Comment: https://github.com/tmcw/node-canvas-animation-example might help

Answer (score 1):

Good question, you could potentially use pixi.js or BabylonJS or something like that to create cool title sequences or data animations.

There's no build-in support for mpeg or mp4 output in HTML5 and JavaScript, as far as I know. However there is this library [ccapture.js](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/) on github, though I haven't tried it yet. The description says that it doesn't render the ouput in realtime so this means you can even do more complex/cpu-heavy animations without skipped frames.